# Running Selenium Script in Chrome browser in android devices

Tags: automated-testing, selenium2, android, mobile

Can any one suggest me how to do a set up to run selenium scripts in chrome browser of android device?

Currently script is running fine in native browser of android device, but the requirement is like to run scripts in chrome browser of android device.

Answer (score 2):

I know you can do this using [Appium](http://appium.io/) and launching the Chrome browser app. The set up is quite a bit more then selenium AndroidDriver.  I have gotten pretty close to doing it. If your developing on windows, one hurdle is the framework seems to be written and maintained by all Mac users so the windows support and documentation is quite scarce.  Also you will need to have root access to any device to run the chromedriver on it, (I reccommend WugFresh universal root kit for Nexus devices).  The chromedriver and appium google group forums are quite good if you get stuck.

Here's a pretty good [blog post](http://maheshambati.wordpress.com/2013/08/23/native-android-apps-automation-with-webdriver-using-appium/) using appium, java, testng, android, and windows to get you started.

Comment: HI,  Thanks for the reply. I started with Appium configuration for running scripts in  chrome browser of android device. Os: windows, Device: Galaxy S3 phone(Rooted). Installed node js and downloaded latest chrome driver. But couldn`t succeed. Getting an error like chromedriver is not found. It would be a great help if u share configuration steps for web application testing using appium (chrome browser).

Comment: What language are you running scripts/tests? Where is the chromedriver not found error displayed? On the script console or appium server console?  Try searching around the [Appium user group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/appium-discuss) for your specific error message. In general that is a great place to start debugging.  Post there if you can't find the solution, but make sure to include copies of the output and details of the steps you took, os, languages, etc.

Answer (score -1):

**Please find below 2 possible solutions that might help:**

---

**1)** Re-download Appium using git, and initialize ChromeDriver from scratch:

```
git clone https://github.com/appium/appium.git
cd appium
reset.bat --android --chromedriver-version 2.9 --verbose
```

then launch Appium with `node .` from the same directory.

---

**2)** Or try to specify full path to ChromeDriver executable with `--chromedriver-executable` command line argument when launching Appium.

Comment: This needs more information to be a useful answer.

Comment: Do you run Node.JS and ChromeDriver on the android device? The question is not about Node.JS, are you making assumptions? I think you miss read the question or you need to go into more details how this solution works :)

Comment: Hey again Dmitry. Just like on the Lockito answer, we need a bit more in the post for someone to follow. Ideally, we explain more than the what: we explain the how and the why as well.

Comment: The question is about Appium, Appium is based on Node.js.
P.S. I will make answer better soon.